QGIS - expression filter doesn't work - number of feature never right
I'm configuring a default value on a shapefile layer, and I'm encountering an issue when attempting to count the number of identical features in the 'num_etude' field.
When I add a new feature with the same 'num_etude', it is either not found or always found, depending on how I set the criteria for identifying identical features.
I'm unsure about how QGIS is counting the number of features..
Here are the code snippets I've used:
aggregate(layer:= 'ZONE_ETUDE', aggregate:='count', expression:= "num_etude", filter:= "num_etude" is not null)

aggregate(layer:= 'ZONE_ETUDE', aggregate:='count', expression:= "num_etude", filter:= "num_etude" = coalesce("num_etude",0))

aggregate(layer:= 'ZONE_ETUDE', aggregate:='count', expression:= "num_etude", filter:= "num_etude" = "num_etude")

The result is always 1, regardless of the value I input in the 'num_etude' field.
I expect the value to be updated to 0 if there is no existing equivalent, 1 if there is only one, and 2 or more if there are multiple identical features.
Understanding what is going wrong here will help me resolve the entire problem. afterward.

Sorry, I had to ask to understand the question again..
So I think the solution is:
aggregate(layer:= @layer, aggregate:='count', expression:= "num_etude", filter:= "num_etude" = attribute(@parent, 'num_etude'))

And the full code:
    if(
aggregate(
    layer:= @layer,
    aggregate:='count',
    expression:= "num_etude",
    filter:= "num_etude" = attribute(@parent, 'num_etude')
) = 0, rand(1, 100000),attribute(get_feature('ZONE_ETUDE', 'num_etude', "num_etude"), 'id'))

